# Is there a way to hide your e-mail address on Google Code projects?

Tags: privacy, google-code

One thing that really bothers me about Google Code is that fact that it puts your Google username up on your projects for the world to view. While it doesn't put the @gmail.com part after the name, it doesn't take a genius spammer to concatenate the part with your user name.

**Is there any way to hide or obscure your Google username on Google Code projects?**

Comment: Supposing  there is no solution for this, you could consider using an email address created for this service - Google Code.

Comment: @MercerTraieste, Yeah that is the alternative. This is going to end with me having 50 or so gmail accounts.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23464

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=60), no. But [post 75](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=60#c75) does mention nicknames being a work in progress.

Comment: He mentions "GMail users now have the option to opt out of directly revealing their email addresses." I remember reading about that before. Any idea how to opt in this feature?

Comment: Nemo, I believe you are already opted into that feature. I think when that was mentioned he was referring to leaving out the @gmail part. As he later says, it's not a great method since it can just be pieced together again.

Answer (score 2):

RobertCollier4's suggestion is not very good, because the other 2 options are not good either. The three options are:
Username display

When I participate in projects, show my identity as:

**BillGatesMS**

Google Account username

**billgatesms@gmail.com**

Email address

**bil...@gmail.com**

Obscured email address for non-project members (project members see full email)

Comment: +1 None of these is at all adequate, so it's looks like a "no" then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is now.
Go to:
https://code.google.com/hosting/settings and change option for "Username display - When I participate in projects, show my identity as."